# Addin Link [URL] to an Image in Excel cell using open xml

Tags: c#, excel, image, openxml

I'm trying to use `AddExternalRelationship` method, but it doesn't work,
simply I want to add Link to File [my file in this case is an image on a server] using **`openXML`**

```cs
using (var newDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(xlsDestFilePath, true)) {
    var run = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Run();
    var picture = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Picture();
    var shape = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml.Shape() {
        Id = "_x0000_i1025",
        Style = "width:453.5pt;height:270.8pt"
    };
    run.Append(picture);
    newDoc.AddHyperlinkRelationship(
        new Uri("URL GOES HERE", System.UriKind.Absolute), true);
}
```

Comment: can you share your code here

Comment: using (var newDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(xlsDestFilePath, true))
            {
                var run = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Run();
                var picture = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Picture();
                var shape = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml.Shape() { Id = "_x0000_i1025", Style = "width:453.5pt;height:270.8pt" };                                           
                run.Append(picture);
                newDoc.AddHyperlinkRelationship(new Uri("URL GOES HERE", System.UriKind.Absolute), true);
            }

Answer (score 0):

Use `AddHyperlinkRelationship`

It is clearly stated in the msdn documentation to not use `AddExternalRelationship`

Refer:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc562653.aspx

```
public HyperlinkRelationship AddHyperlinkRelationship(
    Uri hyperlinkUri,
    bool isExternal,
    string id
)
```

Comment: it it didn't work, can you provide an example please? I used AddExternalRelationship in word document and it worked properly, simply i want to load an image from a url once the file is loaded/opened i don't want to click on the hyperlink to load it

Comment: can you share your code ?, so we get to know what actually you are doing.

Comment: using (var newDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(xlsDestFilePath, true))
            {
                var run = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Run();
                var picture = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Picture();
                var shape = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml.Shape() { Id = "_x0000_i1025", Style = "width:453.5pt;height:270.8pt" };                                           
                run.Append(picture);
                newDoc.AddHyperlinkRelationship(new Uri("URL GOES HERE", System.UriKind.Absolute), true);
            }

Comment: I'm modifying an existing excel file [i created it using epplus]